# iPhone browser defaulting to uppercase for first letter of password fields

Tags: iphone, html, user-interface, safari

I'm writing a login page for a mobile version of my webapp and I have a simple HTML password field like so:

```
<input id="password" type="password" />
```

The only problem is that the iPhone Safari browser capitalizes the first letter of the input by default, which is confusing my users as the password is case sensitive and they do not always realise this is the case.

Does anyone know of a method, tag or otherwise to stop this happening and force the iPhone input to lowercase unless the user specifies otherwise? Or is this simply a feature of the platform that can't be changed?

Comment: the secure text is always case insensitive and the user name you can put the validation for the word capitalization in iphone.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="test1" autocapitalize="none"/>
```

The docs can be found here: [Supported Attributes: autocapitalize](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-autocapitalize)

Comment: Good answer. As Ballu mentions, though, this is unnecessary for input type=password.

Comment: "off" was depreciated in iOS 5.0, you should use "none".
This prevents autocapitalising, but the shift key will still be active by default which is a pain.

Answer (score 66):

You may want to turn off both autocorrect and autocapitalize for password and email fields.

Here are what mine look like:

```
<input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" id="email" name="email" type="text">
<input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" id="password" name="password" type="password">
```

Comment: Why thank you, I _do_ want to turn off both. Excellent suggestion!

Comment: I also use autocomplete="off" and spellcheck="false", for good measure.